# В приложении MFC C++ не работает функция MessageBox()

Tags: c++, mfc

В приложении MFC C++ VS 2015 не работает функция MessageBox(). Подскажите, как справляться. L убирал, пространство имен указывал. Это мое первое приложение MFC С++ – не будьте строги.

```
MessageBox(L"Сообщение", L"Сообщение", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Ошибка  C2660   MessageBoxW: функция не принимает 3 аргументов  MFCApplication5
Ошибка (активно)        аргумент типа "const wchar_t *" несовместим с параметром типа "HWND"    MFCApplication5

Ошибка (активно)        аргумент типа "long" несовместим с параметром типа 
"LPCWSTR"   MFCApplication5

Ошибка (активно)        слишком мало аргументов в вызове функции    MFCApplication5

Comment: Добавь первым параметром NULL чтобы всего их (параметров) было 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MFC, в CWnd есть MessageBox, она "принимает" три параметра: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0eebkf6f.aspx

Судя по ошибке, Вы используете эту функцию вне контекста CWnd, поэтому у Вас используется функция MessageBox из WinAPI. Она "принимает" четыре параметра.
Первый параметр - HWND, подробнее в MSDN: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

MessageBox(NULL , L"Сообщение", L"Сообщение", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONINFORMATION);